# Call powershell.exe from CMD and exit code boolean

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to run a PowerShell command (not script) from a cmd.exe and manage the exit code properly:

```
powershell.exe [bool]((get-service wsearch).status -eq 'Running')
```

But I would like to return the boolean status as the error level.

I would like to echo `%errorlevel%` after running it and use it to determine service status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the PowerShell `exit` command providing the result as an argument. For example:

```
C:\>powershell -command "exit [int]$true;"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\>powershell -command "exit [int]$false;"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Or for your case:

```
powershell.exe -command "exit [int]((get-service wsearch).status -eq 'Running')"
```

Comment: What if the command fails for some reason? Then the exit code is also 1 and this does not mean "the command has worked and exited with the code 1". With this approach consider at least to exit with some different code.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin It still works for me even if the command fails. Presumably because exit is getting the result of the boolean test operator, not the command itself.

Comment: Maybe, on not terminating errors (and correctness of the result is still not clear). But in cases of terminating errors `exit` is not invoked, instead PowerShell should exit itself with 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this variant:

```
CMD I> Set cmd=powershell -c "((gsv wsearch -ea 0).status -eq 'Running')"
CMD I> %cmd% |>nul find "True" && echo RUNNING||echo NOT RUNNING
RUNNING

CMD I> Set cmd=powershell -c "((gsv youka -ea 0).status -eq 'Running')"
CMD I> %cmd% |>nul find "True" && echo RUNNING||echo NOT RUNNING
NOT RUNNING
```